Flatpak-installed Spotify client doesn't evoke the web browser
I'm on Fedora 39 on bspwm (very minimal installation, maybe I'm missing some library necessary for this) and installed Spotify client from flathub using flatpak install flathub com.spotify.Client and the application launches flawlessly. When it asks for log-in, which is supposed to be entered inside a web browser, clicking the button does not lead me to a browser, instead doing nothing. I have looked several places for this, some of which said installing xdg-desktop-portal and xdg-desktop-portal-gtk would solve the issue. I tried with no luck. I tried looking into xdg-settings and setting the default browser in there, also with no luck. Any help appreciated!
